# Finding Maximum Amount specified for Maximum date specified in SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Alright, so my goal with this procedure is to find the Maximum amount payment promise that matches up with the maximum date of the payment promise.  I am going to include the procedure where this pulls from, so you will see 2 procedures here.

This first procedure does pretty close to what I want it to do, but there are 2 issues.  If there are 2 values in the PaymentPromise table with the same date, and that date is the maximum, both values will be returned.  If there are no values in PaymentPromise but the balance is still outstanding, this should be returned with null values under PaymentPromise, but it does not do so.

SQL Server 2008, just so you know.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetPaymentsDue
(
@Username varchar(20)
)
AS
DECLARE @BondAmounts TABLE
(
BondID bigint,
BondAmount money,
BondTotal money,
BondBalance money
)

INSERT INTO @BondAmounts EXEC dbo.GetBondAmounts @Username = @Username

SELECT bonds.BondID, Bond.Agency, Bond.Agent, Bond.Defendant, Promise.ExpectedDate,
Promise.ExpectedAmount, bonds.BondTotal, bonds.BondBalance
FROM @BondAmounts bonds
INNER JOIN Bond ON bonds.BondID = Bond.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, BondID, ExpectedAmount, ExpectedDate, MAX(ExpectedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY BondID) MaxDate
    FROM PaymentPromise
) Promise ON bonds.BondID = Promise.BondID
WHERE bonds.BondBalance > 0
AND (Promise.ExpectedDate = Promise.MaxDate OR Promise.ExpectedDate = NULL)
```

So this first procedure calls the second procedure to get the initial data set to work with.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetBondAmounts
(
@Username varchar(20)
)
AS
SELECT Bond.ID BondID, (ISNULL(Powers.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Charges.Amount,0)) BondAmount,
(ISNULL(BondFee.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Powers.Premium,0) + ISNULL(Charges.Premium,0)
+ ISNULL(Forfeiture.CostOfApprehension,0) + ISNULL(Forfeiture.AmountPaid,0) + Bond.StateTax) BondTotal,
(ISNULL(BondFee.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Powers.Premium,0) + ISNULL(Charges.Premium,0)
+ ISNULL(Forfeiture.CostOfApprehension,0) + ISNULL(Forfeiture.AmountPaid,0) + Bond.StateTax
- ISNULL(BalanceForgiveness.Amount,0) - ISNULL(Payment.Amount,0)) BondBalance
FROM Bond
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Agency, Username FROM UserAgency
    WHERE Username = @Username
) AS UserAgency ON Bond.Agency = UserAgency.Agency
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT BondID, SUM(AmountForgiven) Amount
    FROM BalanceForgiveness
    GROUP BY BondID
) AS BalanceForgiveness ON Bond.ID = BalanceForgiveness.BondID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Bond, SUM(Amount) Amount
    FROM BondFee
    GROUP BY Bond
) AS BondFee ON Bond.ID = BondFee.Bond
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Powers.Bond, SUM(Charge.BondAmount) Amount,
    ISNULL(SUM(Charge.BondPremium), 0) Premium
    FROM Powers INNER JOIN Charge ON Powers.Surety = Charge.PowerSurety
    AND Powers.PowerPrefix = Charge.PowerPrefix AND Powers.PowerNumber = Charge.PowerNumber
    GROUP BY Bond
) AS Powers ON Bond.ID = Powers.Bond
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT BondID, SUM(BondAmount) Amount, SUM(BondPremium) Premium
    FROM ChargeWithoutPower
    GROUP BY BondID
) AS Charges ON Bond.ID = Charges.BondID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Bond, SUM(CostOfApprehension) CostOfApprehension, SUM(AmountPaid) AmountPaid
    FROM Forfeiture
    GROUP BY Bond
) AS Forfeiture ON Bond.ID = Forfeiture.Bond
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT Bond, SUM(Amount) Amount
    FROM Payment
    GROUP BY Bond
) AS Payment ON Bond.ID = Payment.Bond
WHERE UserAgency.Username = @Username
OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @Username AND Admin = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query is quite hard to follow.  Here is the general strategy to getting one row when you want a maximum:

```
with t as (select t.*,
                  row_number() over (partition by <whatever> order by paymentpromisedate desc) as seqnum
           from t
          )
select t.*
from t
where seqnum = 1
```

The second is probably an issue of a left outer join rather than a join.

If you can narrow down where the problem is -- the first or second query -- it would be easier to provide a more detailed answer.

Applied to your query . . .

```
SELECT bonds.BondID, Bond.Agency, Bond.Agent, Bond.Defendant, Promise.ExpectedDate,
       Promise.ExpectedAmount, bonds.BondTotal, bonds.BondBalance
FROM @BondAmounts bonds INNER JOIN
     Bond
     ON bonds.BondID = Bond.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT ID, BondID, ExpectedAmount, ExpectedDate,
             row_number() over (partition by bondid order by expectedDate desc) as seqnum
      FROM PaymentPromise
     ) Promise
     ON bonds.BondID = Promise.BondID
WHERE bonds.BondBalance > 0 and
      (Promise.seqnum = 1 or Promise.seqnum is null)
```

I'm not sure why the left join is not working.  I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Well as I stated above, the first query is where the problem is.  Specifically in the following code:

`LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, BondID, ExpectedAmount, ExpectedDate, MAX(ExpectedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY BondID) MaxDate
    FROM PaymentPromise
) Promise ON bonds.BondID = Promise.BondID`

It returns all values where the Expected Date is Max Date, but I want it to return only a single value, that being the largest Expected Amount.

Comment: The purpose of the second query is so you know where the data is coming from.  The second query is used by another Stored Procedure and has no issues returning all values I need.  This one only returns a value if there is a Payment Promise in the system for it, but it returns multiple if there are multiple Payment Promises on the same Max Date.

Comment: And instead of using {max(expecteddate) over (partition by bondid)} you should use {row_number() over (partition by bondid) order by expecteddate desc) as seqnum}.  Then choose "seqnum = 1" instead of "date = maxdate".

Comment: Alright, and the solution to my second problem is changing the `= null` to `is null`, which is kind of an easy mistake for me.  I have made it before.

Comment: I cannot figure out why the left join would not be working.  If the version I edited doesn't work, you can try changing the second join condition to "bond.BondId = Promise.BondId".  Personally, I like for the join condition to match the immediately preceding table and succeeding table . . . perhaps it somehow makes a difference in this case.  You already took care of the obvious failures, like putting a field from Promise in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Oh, I feel dumb for not noticing that ;)  This may be the thing I like least about SQL . . . they could at least make "= NULL" a syntax error.